# :{PREFIX}* not working as expected

Tags: java, google-admin-sdk

Google documentation defines :{PREFIX}* as returning the list of users starting with the {PREFIX} and followed by any character symbolized by the wildcard character. But when trying it with the sample :Mark* it also returns users named Edward Mark for example.

Code below:

```
Users result = service.users().list()
                .setCustomer("my_customer")
                .setQuery("givenName:Mark*")
                .setOrderBy("givenName")
                .setMaxResults(10)
                .execute();
```

Comment: What was it suppose to return? Edward Mark contains 'Mark' hence the result.

Comment: Based on the google documentation of :{PREFIX}* (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users) it's not supposed to return values with 'Mark' if it is not the first string pattern. Based on the given example on the link, using givenName:Jane* returns "Jane", "Jane Ann", and "Janet" but NOT "Sarah Jane". My above example should return "Mark", "Mark Felix", "Markelle", but NOT "Edward Mark" but as I have said, it also returns "Edward Mark" which is not the expected behavior